# How i can run html file iwith vb in visual studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I tried to run with Process.Start(path of file.html)

```
Private Sub TestΜαθηματικάIΙIToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestΜαθηματικάIΙIToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Process.Start("C:\Mathimatika\3o_test_M-III\test.html")
End Sub
```

but i have this error "The system cannot find the file specified" I'm sure 100% path is correct.

Can anyone suggest me some other way?

thanks in advance

Comment: The html is local if u ask this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this message if something else prevents your process from opening the file, such as if it does not have permissions to access the file, or if the file is locked by another process.

Also, if you're trying to do this from an ASP.Net web site, remember that your code is running on a web server that will not have access to the file system on computer hosting the web browser.

---

Looking again: it's just not escaping the `\` character in the file path. All you need to do is add a `@` so that you get an unescaped string:

```
Private Sub TestΜαθηματικάIΙIToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestΜαθηματικάIΙIToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Process.Start(@"C:\Mathimatika\3o_test_M-III\test.html")
End Sub
```